# What nuances distinguish statuó, cónstituó, and ínstituó?

Tags: vocabulary, nuance, contemporary-latin

I'm asking mostly in the context of living Latin and trying to figure out how to say things like "I decided," "I started a blog," "I set up an organization," "I instituted a policy," and so on, for all of which some version of *statuó* seems appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Excerpted from [*Döderlein's Handbook of Latin Synonymes*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/33197/33197-h/33197-h.htm):

> **Instituere; Instaurare; Restituere; Restaurare.** *Instituere* means to establish a profane, *instaurare*, a sacred, or honorable, or generally important institution, such as sacrifices, sacred games, wars and battles. Hence is *instituere* itself a usual, *instaurare*, a solemn, select expression. In the same manner *restituere* is distinguished from *restaurare*.
>
> **Destinare; Obstinare; Decernere; Statuere; Constituere.** 1. *Destinare* and *obstinare* denote forming a resolution as a psychological, whereas *decernere* and *statuere* as a political, act. 2. *Destinare* means to form a decided resolution, by which a thing is set at rest; *obstinare*, to form an unalterable resolution, whereby a man perseveres with obstinacy and doggedness. 3. *Decernere* denotes the final result of a formal consultation, or, at least, of a deliberation approaching the nature and seriousness of a collegial discussion; *statuere*, to settle the termination of an uncertain state, and *constituere* is the word employed, if the subject or object of the transaction is a multitude. Cic. Fr. Tull. Hoc judicium sic expectatur, ut non unæ rei *statui*, sed omnibus *constitui* putetur.

I've also heard *condere* in reference to organizations and websites, e.g. *Nuperrime situm/sedem ad linguam Latinam pertinentem aliquot homines in rete universali condiderunt.*

Comment: Hmm. I like Döderlein but I'm always hesitant to take him as the last word. For example, in *Letters to Atticus* 47 (III.1), Cicero writes *Intellexi ad iter id quod constitui nihil mihi optius cadere posse quam ut tu me quam primum consequare,* and neither he nor Atticus is a multitude.

Comment: Good point. Neither does his note on *decernere* seem to apply to uses of that word referring to a simple decision by one person, e.g. Liv. 2.45 "reliquam aetatem a republica procul habendam decrevi."
Perhaps, then, we should take these distinctions as applying *only* where these words differ in meaning from the rest. (And unfortunately no clues are given as to how often they differ.)

Comment: After poking around Smith's Copious and Critical (*man* does Google books suck on a phone) I'm beginning to suspect that statuo has a sense of putting something down and constituo has a sense of putting something down and fixing it in place. This would certainly fit with the way prefixes work in Latin verbs, and with the meanings of "con-".  However this is at the moment pure conjecture.   Will add citations when am home.